# Meaning of "stehend inne"

Tags: expression

What is the meaning of this sentence:

> Samson hielt noch in der Tür stehend inne.

I translated the words and it is:

> Samson was holding on the door standing within

which does not have any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb in this sentence is "innehalten" which means to pause. A correct translation is

> Samson paused while he was still standing at the door.

By the way, my translation *standing at the door* is not exactly the same as *in der Tür stehend*, but that is another question.

The German sentence could be written in the perhaps more transparent form

> Samson hielt, noch in der Tür stehend, inne.

Comment: Why didn't you translate it with "Samsom paused while he was still standing IN the doorway"?